# Error in integration between wirecloud and IDM GE (error 404)

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I have deployed a new Wirecloud instance (version 0.7) to a VM. Since, I registered it in the FI-WARE portal, I modified the Django settings in order to use the public IDM GE for security (authentication issues etc).

However, I get the message "Not Found 404. The resource you were looking for doesn't exist" during the Sign in process.

Given that the endpoinds of the IDM GE recently was modified, what about the integration between IDM and Wirecloud (urls, callback urls etc)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade your instance of WireCloud to version 0.7.2, as the support for KeyRock v2.0 was added in that version.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Finally, i solved this problem. There is dependency with the django version (by default, the version 1.4 was installed, but it needs v1.5+).